# how to check if string is number in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle

lets say i have a table like that

```
t:
a b
1 123
2 abc
3  poj
4 159
```

what i want to do is to know whether column b is number or not i tried this

```
select a,b,
case
when IsNumeric(b) then 'Number'
else 'Not Number'
end as c
from table t
```

so i want my output to be like that

```
a b    c
1 123  Number
2 abc  Not Number
3 poj  Not Number
4 159  Number
```

but it gave me error as no function named IsNumeric() in oracle its only in sql server so what should i do?

Comment: simplest way is to use `to_number(<string> default <some number/null> on conversion error)`, then you can use a case statement around that to check if the number returned is the default value, in which case you can check if the original string was that value too (which means it was a number, or NULL if that's what you chose for the default value) or not, otherwise it's a number.